# How to stop a code running in PyScipOpt when it reaches to a specific gap?

Tags: python, neural-network

I´ve solved an optimization problem with `PySCipOpt` in `Python`.

I want to stop running the code when the solution gap is less than 1000.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
model.setParam("limits/gap", 0.01)
```

To stop the solving processes when a gap of 1% is reached.

Answer (score -1):

You can write exit() in the loop.

Comment: I want to stop when the solution gap is less than a specific value. So, I should check this as a condition, if it holds I can use exit(). How can I check this condition?

Answer (score -1):

`exit()` stops script execution, you should use something like this:

```
if solution_gap < '1000':
      break
```

Comment: How to define solution_gap?

Comment: What do you mean with `solution gap` ?

Comment: solution_gap in your answer, How to define that? In other words, how can I define a gap in my model?

Comment: You were asking about a solution to stop running the code when  `condition`. I give you a solution for that